# Playback issues in Audacity and other apps

Tags: sound, virtualbox, audacity, tuxguitar

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on a virtual machine (2 GB RAM, 12 MB video memory) in VirtualBox 5.1. The host OS is macOS Sierra 10.12.5.

Whenever I play a sound on Audacity, **the output sound is garbled and glitchy for a short while and the playhead jumps a couple of seconds ahead**. The sound plays normally after that.

I tried reinstalling Audacity from Ubuntu Software. I also tried installing Audacity from the PPA. But the problem persists.

I'm experiencing similar issues with other apps as well. For example, **in TuxGuitar, the position of the playhead and the actual note being played are not in sync**.

Does anyone know a way to solve this problem? I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Ubuntu Version: 16.04
VirtualBox Version: 5.1.22
Virtual Machine Memory: 2 GB
Virtual Machine Disk Size: 16 GB
Host OS: macOS 10.12.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 18.04, Audacity 2.1.1 and VirtualBox.

I found that by changing Audacity's playback device to "sysdefault" the scratching and jumping goes away.